# For zless to read empty gz file

Tags: linux, gzip, less-unix

I have tried to use zless to read (.gz) files.

```
zless $1.txt.gz
```

However, when (.gz) file is empty, it shows a message

```
"$1.txt.gz" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
```

How to force zless to read an empty gz file without typing Y for many times.

or

Is that possible to return something like

```
$1 is empty
```

Comment: That's not how it behaves on my systems. zless is a simple shell script, so you should be able to make something very similar to it by, for example, forking the original code, or looking at how it behaves and creating a similar script yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zless` is just a wrapper around `less`. You need to look at `man less`:

> -f or --force
>                 Forces  non-regular  files to be opened.  (A non-regular file is a directory or a device special file.)
>                 **Also suppresses the warning message when a binary file is opened.**  By default, less will refuse to open
>                 non-regular  files.  Note that some operating systems will not allow directories to be read, even if -f
>                 is set.

The answer is

```
zless -f "${1}.txt.gz"
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. In this case, if the file is opened, then there is no way to return "$1 is empty", right ?

Comment: As [Petesh pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909881/for-zless-to-read-emtpy-gz-file/42910043#comment72919138_42909881), `zless` is just a small wrapper around `less`. If you want a message like "file is empty", you can create your own wrapper script.